# Java String Output Error Using Java.Util.Scanner

Tags: java, string

I am writing a basic code which will be taking the number of question as input. After that I am using a for loop to Read each question. However, It is not asking for the first question and directly moving to the second question. Here is the code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class quiz
{
    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int numberofquestion,i;
        String[] question;
        question = new String[200];
        System.out.print("Enter the number of Question : ");
        numberofquestion = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The number of question you entered is : "+numberofquestion);
        for(i=0;i<=numberofquestion-1;i++)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter the Question : ");
            question[i] = in.nextLine();
        }
        for(i=0;i<numberofquestion;i++)
        {
            System.out.print("Question = "+question[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-use-nextint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to add

```
 in.nextLine();
```

after the `in.nextInt();`

**Why?** Because `nextInt()` doesn't read the "newline" character in the input, so your `nextLine()` in the loop was consuming it.